# c++ create reference variable inside function

Tags: c++, reference

Suppose I have the following function:

```
void myFunc(P& first, P& last) {
    std::cout << first.child.grandchild[2] << endl;
    // ...
}
```

Now, let's assume that `first.child.grandchild[2]` is too long for my purposes.  For example, suppose it will appear frequently in equations inside `myFunc(P&,P&)`.  So, I'd like to create some sort of symbolic reference inside the function so that my equations would be less messy.     How could I do this?

In particular, consider the code below.  I need to know what statement I could insert so that not only would the output from **line_1a** always be the same as the output from **line_1b**, but also so that the output from **line_2a** would always be the same as the output from **line_2b**.  In other words, I don't want a copy of the value of `first.child.grandchild`, but a reference or symbolic link to the object `first.child.grandchild`.

```
void myFunc(P& first, P& last) {
    // INSERT STATEMENT HERE TO DEFINE "g"

    std::cout << first.child.grandchild[2] << endl; // line_1a
    std::cout << g[2] << endl;                      // line_1b

    g[4] = X; // where X is an in-scope object of matching type

    std::cout << first.child.grandchild[4] << endl; // line_2a
    std::cout << g[4] << endl;                      // line_2b
    //...
}
```

Comment: `const auto& g = first.child.grandchild`?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean the array, like this? http://ideone.com/QKTAv It would work the same way as Seth's comment for a plain, non-C++11-environment array. A vector's even easier: `std::vector<int> &shortName`, and C++11 has `auto` for something even easier.

Comment: auto is going to be the bane of maintenance programmers for many year to come ;-)

Comment: @SethCarnegie I would like to use `auto`, but my code will be compiled on different grid environments that I don't administer, so I doubt I can depend on have a C++11 compliant compiler :(  Thank you though, it's quite a simple (and therefore elegant) solution.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Because programmers are going to get lazy and use auto because the cannot be bothered to work out the type needed - scale that to a old mil LOC project with lots of inheritance/templates - the original programmers function is going to be (mis)used many more times and people are going to get lazy. I think of this a little as C programmers casting things to whatever they want (guilty as charged)

Comment: @AdrianCornish On the contrary, experience with other languages shows that type inference is a very good thing. Not having to figure out the type of something (which can be very obscure, and *changes* as the code changes) just to get a ref or make a copy will be a blessing to all C++ programmers, including maint programmers. edit: casting? It's nothing like casting. Concern about programmers being lazy isn't a reason, it's pointless authoritarianism.

Comment: @AdrianCornish and often with templates, using `auto` (or `decltype` or whatever) is not only convenient but [very nearly] necessary, such as when you're accessing a member of the templated type. In your answer, `first` is a template and `grandchild` has an unpredictable type, which makes that code unreliable. I don't know this for certain but I would bet that `auto` was conceived especially for templates.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Totally agree - but that junior/intern may just think that I'll use auto for everything because it works :-) it is going to happen. Like a lot of C++ there a good ways and bad ways to use it. I've spent most of my career on maintenance programming and I've seen some interesting things and some different misuse of legit standard c++

Comment: @AdrianCornish even if they do use `auto` for everything, Python and Lua and Ruby and Javascript and many other languages with untyped variables all testify that it wouldn't be that bad. It's even less of a non-problem when you have the luxury of using an IDE that will tell you the type of a variable on mouse-hover, like Visual Studio.

Comment: @SethCarnegie And also many perl programmers ;-) but I dislike the use of a strongly typed language (and I do not agree leaving it to the compiler/interpreter to work it out) If you like that style use those languages IMHO. If using a strongly typed language then as the programmer I think you should know (where possible excluding the template example) what types you are dealing with

Comment: @JimBalter Disagree, if you dont like the language use another. Each one has its own plus'es and minus'es - eg I like and usee PHP there I expect auto type conversion - but in C++ I expect things to stay the same. While auto has its place its misuse if highly expected.

Comment: @AdrianCornish auto is in C++11. If you don't like the language, use another that caters to sophists with bad arguments.

Comment: "I dislike the use of a strongly typed language" -- despite apparently having no idea what that is.

Comment: @SethCarnegie "many other languages with untyped variables" -- auto isn't needed for those. The place for auto is in statically typed languages like Haskell, Scala, C#, ... and C++.

Comment: @JimBalter yes, the point was that not knowing the type of the variable by looking at the immediate code is proven not a bad thing by those languages.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I'm not sure that is proven by those dynamically typed languages, which delay type errors until run time and so they may never be detected. It is, however, proven by the statically typed, strongly typed, languages I mentioned, which catch type errors at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that the type of `grandchild` is `T` and size is `N`; then below is the way to create a reference for an array.

```
void myFunc(P& first, P& last) {
  T (&g)[N] = first.child.grandchild;
  ...
}
```

I would not prefer pointer here, though it's also a possible way. Because, the static size of array is helpful to a static analyzer for range checking.

If you are using C++11 compiler then `auto` is the best way (mentioned by @SethCarnegie already):

```
auto &g = first.child.grandchild;
```

Comment: Disagree - it means hard coding array size into the function but the use of N.

Comment: @AdrianCornish Hmm, that's a good point.  Although I will have `N` accessible, I'm also interested in solutions that do not require `N`.  I see your pointer-based solution.  Is there an equivalent reference-based solution not requiring `N` that you can think of?

Comment: And also `grandchild` may or may not be an array.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, if it's not array, then the trivial solution is to have pointer; which is quite known fact. I think the OP has a question regarding particular case of array and his comment above also says that.

Comment: @iammilind if it is an object with an overloaded `operator[]` then a pointer won't work either.

Comment: @SethCarnegie A pointer to an element would work - but not a pointer to the array - your comment is not quite clear on which/

Comment: @AdrianCornish I was meaning a pointer to an element. If you use that, then you have the problem of containers that use non-contiguous storage, as you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Crap - fell into my own trap ;-) - agree

Comment: @AdrianCornish I actually wouldn't have thought of that either if you hadn't mentioned it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Thanks :-. Oh and thats the point of these public discussion - we double check each other . But also a pointer to an element works - as long as you use the container to reassign it to a new element and dont try pointer math.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pointer - then you can change it in the function.

```
WhateverGrandchildIs *ptr=&first.child.grandchild[2];

std::cout << *ptr << std::endl; 

ptr=&first.child.grandchild[4];

std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```

Comment: Pointers really aren't necessary here, where a reference is more than possible.

Comment: Agree but I get the feeling the OP wants to change what the reference points too - could be totally wrong though.

Comment: The reference is for the whole array is what I gathered. Seth's comment should work fine for that.

Comment: Seth's comment is referring to an element as I see it - did I miss something?

Comment: Oops, you're right on that. I'd think it'd still work if you took out the `[2]` is what I meant.

Comment: Maybe wait for the OP to clarify - getting confused now

Comment: I want the pointer (or whatever it will be) to point to the array of grandchild, not simply a single element of the array.

Also, after making this reference/pointer, I will **not** need to modify it to refer/point to something else.  This is purely so that complicated equations can be less messy.

Comment: @synaptik Than my answer will not work for you as is - let me know and I will just delete it Seths comment is a better fit then

Comment: @AdrianCornish But can't you just modify your solution slightly so that it works?  For example, if your pointer points to the 0th element of the array, then can't you just do something like `*(ptr+2)` to refer to the 3rd element?

Comment: I could if you can guarantee the container used for grandchild uses contiguous memory allocation. If it was a std::map for example it would not work

Comment: @AdrianCornish Ah-hah.  I see.